# Support for MS Access

Tags: ms-access, breeze

I am creating a web interface for an old piece of software running on an Access 2000 DB. There is no support for the Entity Framework Model for Access. Is there a way of making a connection to work with breeze?

Comment: I don't mean to sound pessimistic but you are really looking at an uphill climb here, is it really worth it to build an interface for a 13 year old technology that has always had problems with connecting to in the past?  Seems like it would be easier to migrate all of the data  into a new DB than it would to connect to the existing one...

Comment: I kind of agree. However, I have not developed the software and it is still in use in over 500 locations. I have no influence over that! Anyway, I think what I am going to try is linking to the Access tables through SQL Server express and then using the entity framework on that. Sounds good in theory at least!

Comment: So that idea crashed and burned. Problem is, I am running a 64bit machine and SQL Server doesn't want to connect to an Access DSN. It complains of a architecture mismatch and it makes no difference it I use the 32 bit or 64 bit driver to create the dsn to connect to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Ado.net, there is no support from breeze to Access
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mimrantaj/connect-to-access-database-in-C-Sharp-and-ado-net/

Comment: There is no support in Visual Studio for generating the Data Entity Model from anything but SQL Server. However, if I have an ADO.Net connection, can I manually create the DEM for it? Will this then allow Breeze to connect to Access?

Comment: i think that you'll have to write your custom contex provider for breeze and use Ado.net http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/custom-efcontextprovider

Answer (score 1):

I like your idea of putting EF in front of SQL Server express. But if that doesn't work out, your only serious impediment is finding a way to expose access to your Access (chuckle) over HTTP.

Have you got that figured out? Maybe Web API? Because once you figure that out, it will be "easy".

**You do NOT need EF for Breeze clients**. EF is a convenient technology for many .NET developers ... but not everyone. All Breeze really cares about is the data.

You will need to get some some metadata describing your service model (meaning whatever you expose as client-facing objects in your HTTP service). You can produce that in many ways. EF is one way (it's easy) but you can also do it in JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Ward! Have you got any pointers on where to find some tutorials on that. Your website only describes the Entity Framework approach. Craig

Comment: I have just found EntitySpaces ORM. This can create classes based on Access Data. I'm hoping this will work...

Comment: You may still need to create metadata for Breeze. Take a look at the `FoosMetadataProvider` in the *DocCode.DataAccess.EF* of the DocCode sample ([download it](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download)). It generates metadata for a `Foo` class that doesn't actually exist in any database at all. Using EF as a metadata design tool in this way is a fast way to generate metadata on the server for models that are not actually using EF for data access.